# PHP Notice: Undefined variable: str in

Tags: php

My code

```
function rand_string($length) {
$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
$size = strlen( $chars );
for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
$str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ]; // this line error 
 }
return $str;
}
```

Error

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: str in ... on line 5

Comment: define first `$str = '';` and then try to concatinate anything. thanks

Comment: Assign $str =""; before $str .= ?;

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Comment: Please explain what is your issue and what you need

Comment: Trung Thanh   please mark the answer for others help.

Comment: people are not interested in marking the answer. Wastage of effort and time.Deleting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Come on, this is rather simple:

```
function rand_string($length) {
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $size = strlen( $chars );
    $str = "";
    for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ )
        $str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ]; // this line now corrected
    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are "adding" a string to a unknown variable *$str*
The Line

```
 $str .= ....
```

is the culprit. .= is a string concatenation. The long form would be

```
$str = $str . "whatEver";
```

and this whats happens in the background and that 's why PHP give the Undefined Variable Notice.

To get rid of this notice you just have to declare the variable before concatenate it.

```
function rand_string($length) {
    $str = "";
```

Now the $str is known and further strings can be added.